# RoR: How to download a file from ActiveStorage API endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, download, rails-activestorage

I'm trying RoR to make an API Rest and I'm very new to ActiveStorage and I was able to upload a file using it. Now I'm struggling with it to download that file.

I have this model:

```
class Path < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :size, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }, presence: true
  has_one_attached :file_element, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and this controller:

```
class Api::V1::PathsController < ApplicationController
...
def download
   path = User.find(params[:id])
   binary = path.file_element.download
   # stucked here
end
...
end
```

I can't go further. According to the [documentation](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-download) I can use download to have a file. But I can't get this working.

So, please, how to keep going from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it through `send_data`

```
send_data(open(path.file_element.url).read, type: path.file_element.content_type)
```